# an architecture missing when committing and checking out a framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, sdwebimage

I have a project that depends on the SDWebImage framework.
I downloaded the framework, followed the instructions all is good and fine.

I Committed my project to my git repository, and then checked it out on another mac computer.

The problem - one of the architectures (i386) now missing from the SDWebImage.framework file

doing lipo -info SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage on the original computer yields the following line

```
Dev1s-MacBook-Pro:Dev dev1$ lipo -info SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage
Architectures in the fat file:
SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage are: armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64
```

Yet after i checkout the file from the git repo this line reads

```
   Architectures in the fat file:
   SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage are: armv7 armv7s arm64 x86_64
```

I tried manually copying the given frile from computer A to computer B, and the same thing happens.
Do you know why? and How I can fix it? as without the i386 architecture, i can't test on my iphone simulator....